How to use PS/ GraphAPI to get the calendar or events on the public mail box in O365?
We are using the VBScript to get the Exchange 2016 public folder events/calendar, but we have upgrading the mail server to Office 365, the existing VBScript cannot execute to get the calendar/events.
We have explored the solutions, but cannot find any solution to get the details of the public folder.
We have exploring the Graph API and use https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadBasic.All
but got the below error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid version.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-06-17T03:46:00",
            "request-id": "d2d8xxxx-1a84-4e03-a0b9-xxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "d2d8xxxx-1a84-4e03-a0b9-xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}


Currently you can't use the Microsoft Graph to access Public Folder or archive mailboxes.
You can use EWS get items from Public Folders but that API is slated for depreciation in 2026 https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/retirement-of-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-online/ba-p/3924440 .Mapi is the other option for accessing public folder which you can use via Outlook and a third party library like Redemption https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm
The most future proof solution would be to move away from using a Public Folder to another solution, if your using Teams (or going to use) then a channel calendar https://office365itpros.com/2021/01/11/teams-channel-calendar/ would be a good option (Conceptional it's the same as the Public Folder Calendar). If you need to keep it within mail then use a Shared Mailbox or Microsoft 365 Group https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2 . You can then use the Graph via the Graph SDK in PowerShell to do whatever automation of events you need in these calendars you also have the option of using something like Power Automate.

Hello, thank you your comment.  But I want to get the details then post on the Internal Website for colleagues to check the schedule.  It is because we were using the exchange 2016 on last year, the vbscript can get the details then post on it.

So why use a Public folder then ? if you don't have anybody accessing the public folder directly then you can easily just use a Shared Mailbox Calendar then make use of the Graph.
